# sum of roots holomorphic functions on the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $\mathcal{f}$:$\mathrm{D}$$\to$$\mathbb{C}$, $\mathrm{D}$={$\mathcal{z}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : $\vert$$\mathcal{z}$$\vert$ < 1} be a holomorphic, bounded, non-constant function. Show that for the roots ($\mathcal{z_k)_{k=1}^N}$ ($\mathcal{N}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $\cup$ $\infty$)

$\sum_{n=1}^\mathcal{N} (1-\vert$$\mathcal{z_n}$$\vert$) < $\infty$

holds

I know that I need to use Jensen's formula, but it is not clear me that $\mathrm{D}$ contains the unit closed disc, which required for the use of Jensen'formula. 
Then, if $\mathcal{f}$ is bounded on $\mathrm{D}$, I assume

log($\vert$$\mathcal{f(0)}$$\vert$) is also bounded, so is $\sum_{k=1}^N log(\vert$$\mathcal{z_k}$$\vert$), then also $\prod_{k=1}^N$$\vert$$\mathcal{z_k}$$\vert$, and with with a contradiction, I think I can get the final result. But is this correct if $\mathcal{N}$=$\infty$ ?

Comment: If $f(0) = 0$, then $g(z) = f(z)/z^m$ is a bounded holomorphic function with $g(0) \neq 0$ for some $m$. Apart from $0$, $g$ has exactly the same zeros (counting multiplicity) as $f$. If $g$ is constant, the result is immediate. Otherwise, apply Jensen's formula to $g$ on the closed disk $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant r$ for $0 < r < 1$ (such that $g$ has no zeros on $\lvert z\rvert = r$) and let $r \to 1$.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{f(0)}$=0 necessary? And how to guarantee that g has no zeros on $\vert$$\mathcal{z}$$\vert$ = $\mathcal{r}$ ?

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ is not necessary, but it's not ruled out by the assumptions, and if that is the case, that's a small problem in Jensen's formula. Then, to avoid that problem, we divide by the appropriate power of $z$ to obtain a function not vanishing at $0$. Since $g$ is not identically $0$, it has at most countably many zeros in the unit disk, hence there are at most countably many $r\in (0,1)$ such that $g$ has a zero on $\lvert z\rvert = r$. Just avoid these, almost all $r$ work fine.